# Cannot check for null values in sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, f#

Using the F# query syntax I'm trying to get all the records where a certain field is not null, but I can't seem to figure out a way of doing this.

First, I attempted just:

```
query {
    for h in dc.Table do
    where (h.SectorId <> null)
    select h
}
```

But an error stated `The type 'Nullable<Guid>' does not have 'null' as a proper value. To create a null value for a Nullable type use 'System.Nullable()'.` Thus, replacing the `null` with `Nullable()` as suggested, I used:

```
query {
    for h in dc.Table do
    where (h.SectorId <> Nullable())
    select h
}
```

When I use the above query in LINQPad, it does not retrieve any values, even though I know they exist. The issue appears to be in the SQL created:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 UniqueIdentifier = null
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[SectorId], [t0].[Blah], [t0].[Meh], [t0].[DisplayOrder]
FROM [Table] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[SectorId] <> @p0
```

Of course this will not work because `NULL <> NULL` in SQL will always be false; the where should read `WHERE [t0].[SectorId] is not null`. How can I check against null in F# queries?

Comment: Shouldn't you have changed your `null` to `Nullable<Guid>()`?

Comment: @Luv Your first query gives the charmingly unhelpful error "This value is not a function and cannot be applied" on the line with the where clause. The second is what I tried?

Comment: @paul I doubt it; type inference will take care of type parameters.

Comment: @AlexanderR I was just **`Trying`** to help you. As today i was doing some research about **`ANSI_NULL`**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
query {
    for h in dc.Table do
    where h.SectorId.HasValue
    select h
}
```

Comment: I haven't used `query`, but found the answer on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh225374.aspx). That page has lots of examples you may find helpful.